# Как отследить статус выполнения запроса?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, запрос

Добрый вечер. Как отследить статус выполнения запроса? Я начинаю операцию `[requestOperation start]`; и мне нужно знать, когда он закончиться и что при этом будет `Fail or Finish`.

```
   AFHTTPRequestOperation* requestOperation = nil;
    if ([queuedOperationsArray count] > cardIndex)
    {
        requestOperation  = queuedOperationsArray[cardIndex];
    }

    if (requestOperation)
    {
        [requestOperation start];
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание на метод:

```
[requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
// process success here
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
// process failure here
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [документацию](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html), там все написано